Perplexing character: ^V in a terminal used by Neovim
Just found out or seen that a file opened is displaying:
^V

in a terminal utilized by Neovim editor and it really is a single character! Proven by its distinct colorizing
So wondering how can one type it do deliver control+v by most common device used around us?

In Insert mode you can type Ctrl+vCtrl+v.
In Insert mode if you hit Ctrl+v the next character typed is inserted literally.
More information with :help i_CTRL-V
The ^* characters (e.g.: ^V, ^M, ...) are control characters that can inserted that way (e.g.: Ctrl+vCtrl+v, Ctrl+vCtrl+m)
Their ASCII code are 1 for ^A to 26 for^Z.
Their is one special case Ctrl+vCtrl+j that inserts ^@ whose ASCII code is 0 (the null character)
Remark: you can get the ASCII code of a character using the ga keyboard command.
You can also insert character using their ASCII code. To insert ^V whose ASCII code is 22 you can type:

Ctrl+vx22 or using is Unicode code
Ctrl+vu0016.


The C-j thing is a bit of a Vim quirk, IIRC, due to the way nulls are used for line-feeds in Vim (C) text buffers I think?

Also: :help strtrans(), :help digraph-table, :help NL-used-for-Nul
